# Create cards dynamically by looping a file in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

I have been experimenting with Microsoftbot.dialog('showShirts',

```
function (session) {
    var msg = new builder.Message(session);
    msg.attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
    msg.attachments([
        new builder.HeroCard(session)
            .title("Classic White T-Shirt")
            .subtitle("100% Soft and Luxurious Cotton")
            .text("Price is $25 and carried in sizes (S, M, L, and XL)")
            .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, 'http://petersapparel.parseapp.com/img/whiteshirt.png')])
            .buttons([
                builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "buy classic white t-shirt", "Buy")
            ]),
        new builder.HeroCard(session)
            .title("Classic Gray T-Shirt")
            .subtitle("100% Soft and Luxurious Cotton")
            .text("Price is $25 and carried in sizes (S, M, L, and XL)")
            .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, 'http://petersapparel.parseapp.com/img/grayshirt.png')])
            .buttons([
                builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "buy classic gray t-shirt", "Buy")
            ])
    ]);
    session.send(msg).endDialog();
}).triggerAction({ matches: /^(show|list)/i }); bot framework in node js, 
i saw this sample code in the documentation
```

My question is instead of manually typing *new builder.HeroCard()...* how can i create a loop to populate this from a json array?

I have tried this

```
var obj = require("./dummy_json");
msg.attachments([
    obj.shirts.forEach(function(data){
        new builder.HeroCard(session)
            .title(data.title)
            .subtitle(data.subtitle)
            .text(data.text)
            .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, data.image_path)])
            .buttons([
                builder.CardAction.imBack(session, data.title, "Buy")
            ])
    },this)
]);
```

Comment: Wrap this inside a for/forEach call?

Comment: hey @EzequielJadib I tried wrapping the "new builder.HeroCard()..." in a forEach and that returns an empty attachments array. 

`{
  "type": "message",
  "attachmentLayout": "carousel",
  "attachments": [],
  "locale": "en-US",
  "localTimestamp": "2017-07-24T20:26:31.414Z",
  "from": {
    "id": "0db08g0j3blgl1jfmc",
    "name": "Bot"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "default-user",
    "name": "User"
  },
  "inputHint": "acceptingInput",
  "id": null,
  "replyToId": "1kf4ad6jjihlk7k73"
}`

Comment: Add your new code please

Comment: Yeah your code is wrong, you are not adding anything to the array. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing the loop but it seems you are not adding anything to the array.

Try something like this:

```
var attachments = [];
var obj = require("./dummy_json");

obj.shirts.forEach(function(data) {
    var card = new builder.HeroCard(session)
                    .title(data.title)
                    .subtitle(data.subtitle)
                    .text(data.text)
                    .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, data.image_path)])
                    .buttons([
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, data.title, "Buy")
                    ])

     attachments.push(card); 
},this)

msg.attachments(attachments);
```