# How do I add text and buttons in adaptive card using loop

Tags: node.js, azure, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I am using adaptive card for displaying text,images and buttons.
How do I apply for loop to the same. I want to loop text and buttons, please guide.

I refered this  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289623/create-cards-dynamically-by-looping-a-file-in-microsoft-bot-framework) but could not relate with my requirements.
I am unable to add my code it says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"

I want to use for loop for this [example](https://adaptivecards.io/samples/ActivityUpdate.html) Sorry I cannot paste my code.